# ssh session immediately on starting xterm

Tags: ssh, terminal, xterm, iterm2, iterm

What's the most elegant way to start an xterm window that, instead of opening a bash shell for the local computer and requires me to execute my ssh command manually, opens an ssh session for remote computer immediately?

I've seen some tricks involving `SHELL=ssh username@host.domain.com` for related problems. Is that the most natural way to achieve this behavior?

Notes:

- The reason I want to do this is because I often do command line work on my remote ubuntu server from my Macbook. I ssh into this server more often than I do command line work relevant to my local Macbook, so I'd like to optimize my workflow for the ssh case.
- Eventually I want to use iTerm instead of xterm but since iTerm is nowhere near as widespread as xterm I'd prefer to see if there's a general solution that can work on any terminal emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the execute-parameter provided by most of the linux terminal progs:

Examples:
xterm -e "..."
see http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm

xfce-terminal -e "..."
see http://man.cx/xfce4-terminal%281%29